# How do I grab each student’s 3rd max assignment mark in each subject

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to write an sql that will allow me select each student’s 3rd best assignment mark in each subject. I have tried with the query below but it isn't working for me. I will be grateful to get some answers. I am getting an error `[Code: 0, SQL State: 21000]  ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`. 
This is the table structure Students , Courses(Id) , bridging table called StudentsCourses(ID, StudentID,CourseID) and then assignment table which has StudentsCourse(FK) and Grade

```
select max(Assignments.Grade)
from Assignments
where grade < (select max(Assignments.Grade)
         from Assignments
         where grade  <  (select max(Assignments.Grade)
                         from Assignments
                         group by Assignments.StudentCourseID))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select a.*, row_number() over(partition by student_id, subject_id order by grade desc)
    from assignments a
) a
where rn = 3
```

Your question is a bit unclear about the structure of table `assignments`. This assumes that a student is identified by `student_id` and a subject by `subject_id` - you many need to ajust that to your actual column names.

Comment: this is the table structure    Students , Courses(Id) , bridging table called StudentsCourses(ID, StudentID,CourseID) and then assignment table which has StudentsCourse(FK) and Grade

Comment: @Ekaku509: please don't put additional information into comments. [**edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61091250/edit) instead

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by student_id, StudentCourseID order by grade desc) as seqnum
      from assignments a
     ) a
where seqnum = 3;
```

Note:  If all the assignments have the same value, this will return the highest value.

If you want the third highest *distinct* score, then use `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

Comment: this is the table structure    Students , Courses(Id) , bridging table called StudentsCourses(ID, StudentID,CourseID) and then assignment table which has StudentsCourse(FK) and Grade.

Could you explain the row_number and use of dense_rank

Comment: @Ekaku509 . . . Your comment is nice, but your question only references `assignments`, so that is what this answer addresses.  You can read the documentation for Postgres to better understand Postgres functions.

Comment: Yeah, I am actually looking at how I can use the Student Name, and the course Name ad well from the tables I mentioned. How do I do that together with the assignment table? table inclusiveThanks so much. I may have another question about another so i will get some answers about that query

Comment: **Will this be able to find me the  :  the average final mark in each class (assuming only top four assignments per student were counted, if student has less than four assignments assume a score of zero for the remainder ? **


 `select *
       from (
          select s.*, a.grade, row_number() over(partition by s.studentID,s.courseID order by grade desc) as rn
          from assignments a, StudentCourses s
          where a.StudentCourseID = s.StudentCourseID
       ) a
       where rn < 5]`